# Excel, Word, PDFs AND PowerPoint print dialogues

Tags: c#, printing

Anybody know how to get all of these in a C# app that leads the user to a print dialogue screen?
What I mean is this:
In the gui the user selects a document, right clicks on the doc, chooses Print.  Instead of immediately printing out the doc, the print dialogue comes up.

Anybody know the syntax for all of this?  I tried using all of the interops for the MS Office apps and trying the printdialogue method...but no such luck.

Can anybody provide me with some code?  I've seriously been at this for HOURS and can't come up with a thing.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your scenario? Where do users select an Office document? In Explorer? In your own application? Did you already have a look at the `Application.Dialogs` collection?

Comment: i have a separate UI Win form that shows a tree view of all my docs. i'm new to C# so i need all the help i can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe see this previous Q&A:
[send-document-to-printer-with-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218556/send-document-to-printer-with-c)

Or, for a WPF app that prints a FlowDocument :

```
    private void DoThePrint(System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument document)
    {
        // Clone the source document's content into a new FlowDocument.
        // This is because the pagination for the printer needs to be 
        // done differently than the pagination for the displayed page. 
        // We print the copy, rather that the original FlowDocument. 
        System.IO.MemoryStream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        TextRange source = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
        source.Save(s, DataFormats.Xaml);
        FlowDocument copy = new FlowDocument();
        TextRange dest = new TextRange(copy.ContentStart, copy.ContentEnd);
        dest.Load(s, DataFormats.Xaml);

        // Create a XpsDocumentWriter object, implicitly opening a Windows common print dialog, 
        // and allowing the user to select a printer.

        // get information about the dimensions of the seleted printer+media. 
        System.Printing.PrintDocumentImageableArea ia = null;
        System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter docWriter = System.Printing.PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref ia);

        if (docWriter != null && ia != null)
        {
            DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)copy).DocumentPaginator;

            // Change the PageSize and PagePadding for the document to match the CanvasSize for the printer device.
            paginator.PageSize = new Size(ia.MediaSizeWidth, ia.MediaSizeHeight);
            Thickness t = new Thickness(72);  // copy.PagePadding;
            copy.PagePadding = new Thickness(
                             Math.Max(ia.OriginWidth, t.Left),
                               Math.Max(ia.OriginHeight, t.Top),
                               Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeWidth - (ia.OriginWidth + ia.ExtentWidth), t.Right),
                               Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeHeight - (ia.OriginHeight + ia.ExtentHeight), t.Bottom));

            copy.ColumnWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
            //copy.PageWidth = 528; // allow the page to be the natural with of the output device

            // Send content to the printer.
            docWriter.Write(paginator);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i'm not quite sure i need code for a FlowDocument.  The user will try to print the document and just needs to hit a print dialogue so they can choose their printer.