# printing a document programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, printing

If I have adobe reader installed,  is it possible to programmatically print the document to a specific printer without having adobe reader or the printer dialog display (no user intervention)? Any code snippets or sugestions are helpful. I can use any version of the .net framework to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.  IIRC, you can tell acrobat reader to print the document for you via the command line.  But when you do it's going to prompt you via the gui to tell it what printer to use.

---

Edit:

Hmm, maybe you can do it *almost* silently.  Check this link:
http://support.adobe.com/devsup/devsup.nsf/docs/52080.htm

Found via this old answer:
[Send document to printer with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218556/send-document-to-printer-with-c/218677#218677)

Answer (score 0):

Used to do this back in the novell print queue days so it should at least work in theory. If you can figure out a way to convert the PDF into postscript you can then stream it to a postscript printer and print that way.