# Sending String Directly to printer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send document to printer with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218556/send-document-to-printer-with-c)

I want to to Send a String Value directly to printer. of course it is very better that I can send a datatable to printer. but first of all I want to know how I can send my String Value without any prompting for end user to printer. 
I have searched for 3 hours in internet but found no response.
please help me. Thx :)

Comment: Ironically this is the first hit on Google when you search for this.

Answer (score 19):

you can use `PrintDocument` under `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace. `Print` method will print the string using your default printer

```
string s = "string to print";

PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
    e1.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

};
try
{
    p.Print();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
}
```

Found example from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/93e54c4f-fd07-4b60-9922-102439292f52/)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you were searching for, but here are two articles I found in 1 minute on MSDN about printing.  In a nutshell, a `PrintDocument` class wraps up the functionality with the `PrintPage` event being raised for each page being printed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx

Comment: I believe OP want to send text directly to text printer. like what we used to do pre-windows on com port printers. a text drawn on graphic is not actually a string sent to printer, it is a picture.