# C# Sending String To Printer Not Working With Courier

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, printing

My IDE is .Net 2008 using C#.  I need to send a string to a printer in a non proportionally spaced font.  As an example lets say the string = "Hello World" and the printer is "Printer1"

I followed the advice of this stackoverflow post:
[Sending String Directly to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434938/sending-string-directly-to-printer)

When I set the font to "Times New Roman" or "Comic Sans MS", it works.  But when I use Courier, I get a nonproportionally spaced font.

I am using the exact coding as the post that I have cited.  Why won't Courier give me the non proportionally spaced font I need?  Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance,
Harvey Nusbaum

Comment: Please learn writing text. "But when I use Courier, I get a nonproportionally spaced font." is not the same as "C# Sending String To Printer Not Working With Courier".

Answer (score 4):

Courier is a monospace font. All of its characters have the same width.

Comment: ;) Funny how some people do not even look at the fonts they sent - it is easy to see in any font management that Courier is not proportional. In fact it is good so - it is a font made for Shells / CmdLine interface, not for printing "normal text".