# how to convert file into pdf instead of sending it to a printer?

Tags: vb.net

Im new to vb.net and I have a file and instead of sending it to a printer I want to convert it to a PDF from any ideas on how O can make this work?

Im using vb.net 2010

Thanks all answers are appreciated

Comment: Install PDF printer driver and print to pdf

Comment: is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163420/printing-to-a-pdf-printer-programatically?rq=1

Comment: Have you figured this out yet Jeline?

Comment: Actually no but I found another way though Thanks

Answer (score 1):

cutepdf (for a printer driver that outputs PDF files), or pdfsharp (free software library that allows you to create pdf files programatically)